# Annoying Video lag in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, video, radeon

Recently, I switched from 16.04 to 18.04 and have been experiencing this annoying video lag/stutter in Youtube and other videos played in my laptop. I have look around all over the internet and although this question has been asked several times, no solutions have yet been provided with posts even saying that a bug report has been filed.(This is a long time ago). I am posting to see if this issue has been resolved or do I have to live with this video-lagging for the moment.

My laptop model is hp 15-bs179tx which uses a Radeon Graphics card.

Is there a solution to this problem?